# How to get the ChromeDriver automatically updated through Python selenium after compiling using Pyinstaller

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I use to pack the Chromedriver into my exe package too but as people say it changes quite frequently.

So I try the auto check for update method using the selenium import webdriver which also worked like a dream in the IDE however when I compile the code to exe file using Pyinstaller method it then falls and will no longer download the update to my temp MEIPASS location where I later execute the driver for the remainin part of my program.
Could this be windows some how blocking this type of request now it is within an exe file?

Just as an update here it is probably because I am unsure where the autoupdater extracts the new chromedrive to does anybody know where the driver will be placed when it updates?

Answer (score 12):

There is a python pakage called `chromedriver-autoinstaller`. It can be used to auto-update chromedriver
You can install it by using `pip install chromedriver-autoinstaller` command.

```
import chromedriver_autoinstaller


chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()  # Check if the current version of chromedriver exists
                                      # and if it doesn't exist, download it automatically,
                                      # then add chromedriver to path
```

Comment: thanks for the info, I eventually found some code that I could implement into my existing code. Basically it has links to go check if there is an update if so download it to the folder where the user installs my exe file. with a bit of jigging around with the overall program I got it working ok so far..

Comment: can we make this executable?

Comment: @Hu66s Yes we can make it executable using pyinstaller

Answer (score 7):

**webdriver-auto-update**

There is a package in PyPI and GitHub called `webdriver-auto-update`, that you could use for a simple and effective way to download chrome driver automatically.

***Program Functionality***

1. Detects local chromedriver driver version on your computer and compares it with the latest version available online.
2. The latest online version/release will be downloaded automatically if it does not match your local version.

**Installation:**
Make sure you have Python installed in your system.
Run the following in your terminal to install:
`pip install webdriver-auto-update`

**Example**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_auto_update import check_driver


# Pass in the folder used for storing/downloading chromedriver
check_driver('folder/path/of/your/chromedriver')

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
```

Reference link:

https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-auto-update/
https://github.com/competencytestlvl/webdriver_auto_update

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pip uninstall webdriver-manager and after pip install webdriver-manager, and it´s done.